# Batch file to use cd without opening new window

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to be able to type "asm" in cmd prompt and have it automatically switch to the c: drive and enter two directories. I wrote this in a batch file:

```
c:
cd \usr\masm
PAUSE
```

Then I used a bat-to-exe converter to create `asm.exe`, which I then moved to the `C:\Windows\System32` folder so that I could execute the `asm.bat` file. Unfortunately, this opens a new command window, and the prompt then looks like this:
[image]
Once you press enter the command window dissappears. I'm **really new** to creating and working with .bat files, how can I execute the .bat file in the cmd window already open without opening a new window, and how can I keep it open so that I can continue using the cmd prompt.

Any help greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: why did you convert it to an exe instead of leaving it as a bat file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to leave it as a bat file. You should define a directory to put your bat files (like asm) in (like c:\bin or c:\bat) and change the path to include that directory. They you could enter the name of the bat file from anywhere and it would do what you want. When the bat file finished, it would simply leave you with the command prompt.
If you move to a new machine, you can copy the directory and set the path on the other machine.

Answer (score 2):

You should leave it as a .bat file, because you are not making an executable, you are making something you will run on an executable (cmd).

Comment: Oh I see what I'm doing now. So do I need to just put my .bat file in `C:\Windows\System32`? Im about to try that

Comment: It should work. You can also put it in another directory, then you add the directory to the %PATH% variable, but try with your idea first.